# What is the unit of $f(\theta)$ if $f(\theta)=\theta^2-\sin(\frac{\theta}{5})$?

Tags: trigonometry

Given a function $f(\theta)=\theta^2-\sin(\frac{\theta}{5})$.
What is the unit of $f(\theta)$ ?

I know exactly

- $\theta$ is in radians (a unit of angle).
- $\theta^2$ is in square radians
- $\sin(\frac{\theta}{5})$ is a real number (ratio)

What is the reason why we can subtract $\sin(\frac{\theta}{5})$ from $\theta^2$ if their unit is different?

Comment: Radian has no dimension. Therefore radian or radian square is the same.

Comment: Values that have no dimension are often called *pure numbers* or [dimensionless quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity).

Answer (score 1):

I cancel this question.

By definition, $\theta = \frac{s}{r}$, where

- $\theta$ is the subtended angle in radians,
- $s$ is arc length, and
- $r$ is radius. $s$ and $r$ will have the same unit.

Hence $\theta$ is dimensionless and the unit of $f(\theta)$ will just a real number.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The $\theta$ in this formula is unitless, and corresponds (not equals) to the angle ‘$\theta$ radians’. Similarly, the natural sine function accepts, say, the pure number ‘7’, rather than the angle ‘7 rad’, as input.